# Using SQL AND OR together not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, logical-operators

I am trying to use the sql statement below to get the records where the city is Atlanta and the taxonomy code can be 2 different values. It isn't working properly because it is not giving me just Atlanta. If I remove the last `OR` condition it works perfectly, but I need to have it be either taxonomy value.

```
SELECT NPI, ...
FROM  NPIData
WHERE ([Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] = 'ATLANTA')
  AND ([Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '122300000X')
   OR ([Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '1223G0001X')
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your code has no sense

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`OR` has lower precedence rather than `AND`, so you should use parenthesis:

```
WHERE [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] = 'ATLANTA' 
  AND ([Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '122300000X' OR
       [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '1223G0001X')
```

A much better option here is to just use `in`:

```
WHERE [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] = 'ATLANTA'
  AND [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] in ('122300000X', '1223G0001X')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE     ([Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] = 'ATLANTA')
AND ([Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '122300000X' OR [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] = '1223G0001X')
```