# Problem with filter a integer variable in SQL

Tags: sql, filter, integer

I am trying to filter the data I have only for years between 2007 and 20011. The variable I want to filter is an integer`ano`. The query is running but it is not filtering the data in this variable, but it is working to filter the other variable (`conta`).

```
SELECT 
    `ano`, `sigla_uf`, `id_municipio`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN (`conta` = 'Rec Tributária') THEN (`valor`) END) AS `tax_fees`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN (`conta` = 'Impostos') THEN (`valor`) END) AS `tax`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN (`conta` = 'IPTU') THEN (`valor`) END) AS `iptu`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN (`conta` = 'ITBI') THEN (`valor`) END) AS `itbi`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN (`conta` = 'ISSQN') THEN (`valor`) END) AS `issqn`
FROM
    (SELECT 
         `ano`, `sigla_uf`, `id_municipio`, `conta`, `valor`
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              CAST(`ano` AS INT) AS `ano`, `sigla_uf`, `id_municipio`, 
              `estagio`, `portaria`, `conta`, `estagio_bd`, 
              `id_conta_bd`, `conta_bd`, `valor`
          FROM 
              `basedosdados.br_me_siconfi.municipio_receitas_orcamentarias`)
     WHERE
         (`conta` = 'Rec Tributária' OR `conta` = 'Impostos' OR 
          `conta` = 'IPTU' OR `conta` = 'ITBI' OR `conta` = 'ISSQN' 
          AND ano >= 2007 AND ano < 2012))
GROUP BY 
    `ano`, `sigla_uf`, `id_municipio`
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read - and to write!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SQL AND OR together not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968452/using-sql-and-or-together-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

This means that your:

```
 WHERE
     (`conta` = 'Rec Tributária' OR `conta` = 'Impostos' OR 
      `conta` = 'IPTU' OR `conta` = 'ITBI' OR `conta` = 'ISSQN' 
      AND ano >= 2007 AND ano < 2012))
```

actually is read as:

```
 WHERE
     (`conta` = 'Rec Tributária' OR `conta` = 'Impostos' OR 
      `conta` = 'IPTU' OR `conta` = 'ITBI' OR
       (`conta` = 'ISSQN' AND ano >= 2007 AND ano < 2012))
```

Instead do:

```
 WHERE
     (`conta` = 'Rec Tributária' OR `conta` = 'Impostos' OR 
      `conta` = 'IPTU' OR `conta` = 'ITBI' OR `conta` = 'ISSQN')
  AND ano >= 2007 AND ano < 2012
```

Which also can be written as:

```
 WHERE `conta` IN ('Rec Tributária', 'Impostos', 'IPTU', 'ITBI', 'ISSQN') 
   AND ano >= 2007 AND ano < 2012
```